# Save array of objects in Postgresql using Sequalize.js

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have comething like this

```
[{  
  "id":"3",
  "clientName":"John Doe",
  "address":"street, 15",
  "latitude":"50.1212",
  "longitude":"30.1111",
  "timeFrom":"2017-04-05T14:48:00.000Z",
  "timeTo":"2017-04-05T15:48:00.000Z",
  "comments":"call before delivery"
}]
```

This is my part of my model:

```
Order = sequelize.define('Order', {
latitude: {
  type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
  allowNull: false,
  defaultValue: null,
  validate: {
    min: -90,
    max: 90
  }
},
longitude: {
  type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
  allowNull: false,
  defaultValue: null,
  validate: {
    min: -180,
    max: 180
  }
},
{
classMethods: {
  associate: function (models) {
    Order.belongsTo(models.User);
  }
}
});
return Order;
```

How to write array of object via Sequalize.js? If I'm trying to write object, it's pass fine, but with [{},{}] got some troubles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to start here with .bulkCreate() - http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/instances/#working-in-bulk-creating-updating-and-destroying-multiple-rows-at-once

It can take an array of objects and write them all as long as the keys in the object match the column names.